# Why is my flyout menu hiding underneath some content

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a strange situation where a flyout menu is disappearing under a shopping cart bar at the top of my website's page. The flyout menu is set to z-index:9999 and the the bar is set to 99, yet the bar is being rendered on top of the flyout menu. Is there some other system which can override z-index stacking of positioned block-level elements and if so, how can I adjust it?

An example of a page where this is http://procadsys.worldnz.co.nz/component/mijoshop/account/login

Any thoughts on why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: your drop down menus are all over the place.. need to fix that issue will help you clear out many bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `#Menu-Bar` element has a low `z-index`. Change that to `9999` and your initial problem is solved.

Consider that `position:relative` will preserve this `z-index` for its children, so if the topmost parent is lower than another element competing for the same level it will be placed beneath, even if a child claims to have a `z-index` greater than another element outside of the element chain. Relative is relative, in other words. So `9999` the way you have it is only `9999` over any item within the `z-index` of `50` that you currently have the parent set for.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `z-index` styles on the `#header_oc`, `#cart`, `#search_oc`, `#welcome` elements and it works fine.